# MySQL Databases Corrupted

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb, corrupt-data

We run a MySQL Database 5.5 server on a Windows Server 2008 R2 KVM VPS, where our system automatically sets up new databases for customers as needed. A completely separate drive/partition ran out of space yesterday (had no files associated with the MySQL DB) but seemingly has corrupted the MySQL Database.

In reviewing the log files, I can see that the InnoDB is corrupted but cannot make heads or tails of what the problem is or how to resolve it. Can anyone help explain what is these errors mean so I may be able to repair it?

```
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
00000001401198BD    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
000000014011E79A    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
0000000140159697    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
0000000140159F53    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
00000001400F05AD    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
00000001400F07C8    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
00000001400F105C    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
00000001400F4FB3    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
00000001400DA97C    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
00000001400C338C    mysqld.exe!my_osmaperr()
0000000076C0652D    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
0000000076D3C541    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

InnoDB: Thread 408 stopped in file hash0hash.c line 146
```

http://justpaste.it/efuh

Answer (score 2):

The critical error is

```
140217 18:51:48  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2052 in file btr0cur.c line 270
InnoDB: Failing assertion: btr_page_get_next(get_block->frame, mtr) == page_get_page_no(page)
```

That means that a pointer to the next page in a leaf B+tree index page points to the wrong page. Every page has its own page_id in the header.

To fix it start MySQL with innodb_force_recovery=4 and dump all tables with mysqldump in order to re-create InnoDB tablespace from scratch. It's quite probably mysqldump will fail of some tables (because there is no consistent list of page pointers). It that case dump the table in ranges of PK or use a script like [this](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb)

**UPDATE**: Data recovery toolkit moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb)

Comment: I was able to start it with innodb_force_recovery=4 and have mysqldump running now, exporting all databases to "database.sql". As I am not clear on the last instructions, once this is complete, should I setup a new MYSQL Database (clean install VPS) and import this SQL?

Comment: The mysqldump still seems to be running, but the other console window that is opened for mysqld just started spamming InnoDB errors about "May have copied the tablespace but not the log files"

Comment: InnoDB stores data in leaf pages of B+tree index. The leaf pages are connected in a two direction list. Your MySQL crashed because this list is broken for some index. mysqldump has to scan a table i.e. follow the list of pointers. That's why I suspect that mysqldump may crash mysqld on some table. If that happens dump the table in ranges of primary key. Let's say the table has id as the primary key. id is between 1 and 1000. If "select * from table" crashes mysqld then "select * from table where id <= 1 and id <  500" may not. Choosing ranges of id you may dump as many records as possible.

Comment: Forgot to mention - it's better to dump each table separately