# Cannot start MySQL daemon, puppet dashboard

Tags: mysql, nginx, puppet, dashboard

I'm having problems starting MySQL daemon on centos 6 running nginx and puppet dashboard. I have tried

- myisamchk --silent --force */*.MYI
- Forcing InnoDB Recovery

but still getting following errors:

> InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
>   161106 15:37:50
>   InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 0 27370367, 42 rows to undo
>   161106 15:37:50
>   InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139635132954368 in file btr/btr0cur.c line 201
>   InnoDB: Failing assertion: btr_page_get_prev(get_page, mtr) == buf_frame_get_page_no(page)

Comment: [Try to read this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838337/mysql-databases-corrupted) and apply what the answer suggested. I don't know if your question is possible duplicate, but that's one ugly error you got there. I wish you good luck hunting that gremlin that's bugging your code

Comment: thanks ! ill try anything at this point :D